# How to get the text value of JRadioButton

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton, buttongroup

I am creating a project in java. My Program has 80 JRadioButtons .... I need the get the text value of them.. Now these radiobuttons are added to ButtonGroup(each has 4 radio buttons)...

I know how to get the text value from the radio button by this following code

```
radiobutton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String q1=e.getActionCommand();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, q1);
            }
        });
```

Now is there any easy way to do this? because i will have to do this above code for 80 times(for eighty radiobuttons if i use the above use the  above method

Additional Info- I have Total 20 ButtonGroups each with 4 radio buttons. So(80 radio buttons).

Comment: I'd be interested to see just what you're checking with this huge number of JRadioButtons. Can you tell us more about just what this part of the code is doing?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels that my ... , I think that JSlider should be more than an alternative,

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels I am creating Faculty Feedback System...They specifically told us to use RadioButtons... There are four options for each question... There are total 20 questions.

Comment: still don't understand why you need the actionCommand (especially not in the actionListener) - or do you want to tell the user "cool- correct choice!" vs. "oops ... try another!" the moment they select one of the choices?

Answer (score 3):

```
I have Total 20 ButtonGroups each with 4 radio buttons. So(80 radio buttons).
```

then easiest way is

```
String actionCommand = "";
ButtonModel buttonModel = myButtonGroup.getSelection();
if (buttonModel != null) {
   actionCommand = buttonModel.getActionCommand();
} else {
   // buttonModel is null.
   // this occurs if none of the radio buttons 
   // watched by the ButtonGroup have been selected.
}
```

Comment: That can work well, so 1+, but you must take care to check that the ButtonModel returned by `getSelection()` isn't null before calling `getActionCommand()` on it. If you don't mind, I'd like to edit your post to reflect this. Also, there's no need to call `toString()` on the value returned by `getActionCommand()` since it returns a String.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full of Eels The string actionCommand is not printing the text of JRadiobutton, but it prints null.. it goes in the (if buttonModel !=null) condition... then it prints null... My Code is as follows       if(buttonModel!=null){actionCommand=buttonModel.getActionCommand(); System.out.println(actionCommand);}

Comment: @mKorbel I am having problem with the above suggestion by Hovercraft Full of Eels can you help me..

Comment: @Tuhin Bhatt there hard to help you without see what you are tried, update your question with rellevant code, then anyone will be to able to help you

Answer (score 2):

May be instead of defining action-listener for each radio-button individually, you should define a common action-listener for all the radio-buttons.

e.g.

```
public class RadioActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //String q1=e.getActionCommand();

        //Use the ActionEvent#getSource() method which gives you the reference to the
        //radio-button that caused the event
        JRadioButton theJRB = (JRadioButton) e.getSource();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, theJRB.getText());
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it as follows:

```
ActionListener radioAL = new RadioActionListener();

radiobutton1.addActionListener(radioAL);
radiobutton2.addActionListener(radioAL);
```

Also, the [`ActionEvent#getActionCommand()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand%28%29) returns the command string associated with the action not **extacly** the text of command-component.

Comment: There is no need to create 80 RadioActionListeners. Create one and share it for all the radio buttons. That is why you write the generic code to get the source of the event from the ActionEvent.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are facing this problem is because you created every JRadioButton manually, I guess (instead of a loop).

If you really can't do it otherwise, you can use some intelligent code:

```
Container c = ...; // The component containing the radiobuttons
Component[] comps = c.getComponents();
for (int i = 0; i < c.getComponentCount(); ++i)
{
    Component comp = comps[i];
    if (comp instanceof JRadioButton)
    {
         JRadioButton radiobutton = (JRadioButton) comp;
         // add the listener
         radio.addActionListener(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to implementing a design like you desire (I think) is to use arrays to their fullest power. For instance, you could have a 2-Dimensional array of String that holds the JRadioButton texts, and a 1-Dimensional array of ButtonGroups and then be able to easily set up your GUI and query your GUI with for loops and nested for loops (and using the excellent suggestion of mKorbel).

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo002 extends JPanel {
   public static final String[][] RADIO_TEXTS = {
      {"A1","A2","A3","A4"}, {"B1","B2","B3","B4"}, 
      {"C1","C2","C3","C4"}, {"D1","D2","D3","D4"}, 
      {"E1","E2","E3","E4"}, {"F1","F2","F3","F4"}, 
      {"G1","G2","G3","G4"}, {"H1","H2","H3","H4"}, 
      {"I1","I2","I3","I4"}, {"J1","J2","J3","J4"}, 
      {"K1","K2","K3","K4"}, {"L1","L2","L3","L4"}, 
      {"M1","M2","M3","M4"}, {"N1","N2","N3","N4"}, 
      {"O1","O2","O3","O4"}, {"P1","P2","P3","P4"}, 
      {"Q1","Q2","Q3","Q4"}, {"R1","R2","R3","R4"}, 
      {"S1","S2","S3","S4"}, {"T1","T2","T3","T4"}
      };

   private ButtonGroup[] btnGroups = new ButtonGroup[RADIO_TEXTS.length];

   public Foo002() {
      JPanel radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 2));
      for (int i = 0; i < RADIO_TEXTS.length; i++) {
         JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 0));
         btnGroups[i] = new ButtonGroup();
         for (int j = 0; j < RADIO_TEXTS[i].length; j++) {
            String text = RADIO_TEXTS[i][j];
            JRadioButton rBtn = new JRadioButton(text);
            rBtn.setActionCommand(text);
            btnGroups[i].add(rBtn);
            panel.add(rBtn);
         }
         panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
         radioPanel.add(panel);
      }

      JButton getRadioChoicesBtn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Get Radio Choices") {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            for (ButtonGroup btnGroup : btnGroups) {
               ButtonModel btnModel = btnGroup.getSelection();
               if (btnModel != null) {
                  System.out.println("Selected Button: " + btnModel.getActionCommand());
               }
            }
         }
      });
      JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
      btnPanel.add(getRadioChoicesBtn);

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(radioPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("RadioPanels");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new Foo002());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }

}
```

Comment: techically correct, but ... hey, we in OO-land. An array of arrays to model a bunch of questions with choices is ... pre-historic <g>

Comment: @kleopatra: Agree. This is simply an SSCCE for proof of concept. In real life the questions wouldn't be part of the code but of the data.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
   {
   ...
   String nomSelected = getSelectedButtonText(jbgVariables);
   ...
   }

   String getSelectedButtonText(ButtonGroup buttonGroup) {
       Enumeration<AbstractButton> enu = buttonGroup.getElements();
       while (enu.hasMoreElements()) {
          AbstractButton button = enu.nextElement();
          if(button.isSelected())
              return button.getText();
    
    }

    return null;
  }
```