# How to submit multiple vales from form control to the database

Tags: java, radio-button, selected, recording

I have 8 MC questions in a panel. When submitted, I want all the selected answer to be recorded in the database. However, my code is only recording 1 question. Here is the code. (Note: All the jRadioButton names are not same since they are in one panel together.)

Here is the code :

```
public void submitButtonClicked(){

                for(int i=1;i<9;i++){
                username = "Smith";
                questionID = i;
                if(jRadioButton1.isSelected()){answer = jRadioButton1.getText();}
                else if(jRadioButton2.isSelected()){answer = jRadioButton2.getText();}
                                    if(jRadioButton3.isSelected()){answer = jRadioButton3.getText();}
                else if(jRadioButton4.isSelected()){answer = jRadioButton4.getText();}

// and So on until the question 8. 
}
```

Comment: please format your code for readability, and include the rest for a better answer, including the submission code.

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating an array or ArrayList of the ButtonGroups for each JRadioButton cluster. You can then use a for loop to get the selection from each ButtonGroup which is the model of the JRadioButton selected, and if not null, get its actionCommand String.

For example, please look at my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8234580/522444).

Comment: Hi bro, I have to use Java Eclipse Visual Editor for my project. Therefore, I cannot create the jRadioButtons by typing codes. Mine is just like select jRadioButtons component and drop to the Panel. By the way, I got multiple ButtonGroup (eg. 1 ButtonGroup for question 1 and another new ButtonGroup for question 2.) and I am recording my answers with Microsoft Access database. And if possible can help me also with whether this particular selected radibutton is true or not (Checking answers)? Thanks a lot bro. I will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution only one value is recorded because if one if statement is executed then it will bypass all other else if statements.

You could create a array of jradiobuttons and then use them in for loop,traversing each button one by one and then recording its answer.

Comment: Can give me an example of the codes? By the way, I am using Visual Eclipse. Therefore, I got multiple radio buttons with different name.