# How to find out what is the name of my JRadioButton which is created in foor loop

Tags: java, swing

I have  a few questions but i will ask one question at the time, this time the question would be: how to make `JRadioButton` with for loop but to know what name it took so i could later call it to have some action method, for example my code:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < excavators.length; i++) {
        value = excavators[i];
        zaBag.add(new JLabel(value));
        zaBag.add(new JRadioButton());
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the text value of JRadioButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231663/how-to-get-the-text-value-of-jradiobutton)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really do that but changing your approach so instead of assigning a JLabel for each JRadioButton, you can set the text for the radio button using:

`jRadioButton.setText(value);` or in your case `new JRadioButton(value);`

Now I don't fully understand what do you mean by:

> but to know what name it took so i could later call it to have some
>   action method

But I'll assume that you can't get the text of the JRadioButton because of the associated label and since the above solved the problem you can use the following steps **to check if a certain button is clicked and return it's text**:

**1**-Loop around your `JRadioButtons`:

**2**-Use this check and return when the button is the selected on:

```
if (button.isSelected()) {
                return button.getText();
            }
```

Comment: Sorry i did not said properly what i want. i meant that when i create radio button with for loop and put it on my panel, i do not know what is the name of object radio button so i can not assign some method what to do when someone clicks on it

Comment: aha got you, and that's because you are using a JLabel next to the button instead of assigning a text to the button itself, I'll add what to do in steps to check if a button is clicked! and hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

```
    zaBag.add(new JLabel(value));
    zaBag.add(new JRadioButton());
```

Don't use two components. A `JRadioButton` should also contain the text of the button:

```
    //zaBag.add(new JLabel(value));
    zaBag.add(new JRadioButton(value));
```

Now the button is clicked you can just use the `getText()` method.

> I have a few questions but i will ask one question at the time

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more information and examples.

Read other sections of the tutorial first before asking further questions. The tutorial contains all Swing basics.

Edit:

> i do not know what is the name of object radio button so i can not assign some method

The name is irrelevant. You either:

1. Assign a unique listener to each radio button as you create the radio button so you can invoke a specify method
2. You get the text of the radio button and invoke the method based on the text.

The first option is the best option because any code that uses nested if/else statement is poorly designed.

Comment: Thanks camickr, you understood me.although i did not properly expressed myself

Comment: @Mapet, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.